# Google drive API (java) : Downloaded file is not the latest version

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am facing the following issue when downloaded file from a personal drive.

I download - using *java google drive API v3* - a file from a drive I am connected to (still using APIs). I have followed provided samples from [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/java).

The code to download file is

```
try(OutputStream os = Files.newOutputStream(res)) {
  drive.files().get(fileId).executeMediaAndDownloadTo(os);
}
```

Issue is related to the downloaded file content.

Indeed, most of the time, its content is not the latest version (but a previous one).

I don't understand the behavior yet, but I noticed this :

- I upload a *docx* file to my drive
- I modify it (adding text, changing styles, ...)
- I wait for *google drive page/tab* statut *document has been saved* (**checked cloud** icon)
- I launch my java program to download the file.
  --> I've got the original file.
- I close google drive tab (in which document was modified) and relauch my program
  --> downloaded document is the good one (holding changes).

Is there anything wrong in my process ?

- some cache issue ?
- can we check file statut through google APIs ?
- ...

I will appreciate any help, thank you
Nicolas